# HELP ME WITH BCH IN A MULTISIGN ADDRESS

Tags: private-key, electrum, bitcoin-cash, multi-signature

Hy to everyone, Just some days ago I send for error some BCH to my BTC Wallet. I use ELECTRUM. I realized after that I made a mistake with the address and I tried to recover, I import my private key in the electrum cash wallet but nothing, I tried also to import the seed nothing again. I check and I realized also that my private key not correspond to my address. My address start with the number 3 and I discovered that is a multi-sign address. I don't understand how I am using a multisig address when I didn't choose that, but anyway my problem persist and someone could help to find a way to have back my BCH? How can I export the correct key of my address I don't know what I can try anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses starting with "3" do not always correspond to a multisig address. Such addresses are called [P2SH](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0013.mediawiki) (Pay-to-Script-Hash) addresses. In order to get your bitcoins back from such addresses you need to know the script corresponding to the address and provide the right arguments. In most cases this is indeed a MultiSig address. But with electrum it is more likely that this is a [P2SH-P2WPKH](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#p2wpkh-nested-in-bip16-p2sh) (Segwit) address, if you used a [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) mnemonic seed and the Derivation Path [m/49'/0'/0'](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0049.mediawiki) . In that case you only need your public key hash to claim your BCHs back. If i understand correctly you only need to provide

> 0x160014<20-byte-public-key-hash>

as script signature in your transaction to fullfill the requirements in a non segwit environment.

Comment: OK. So I should write what you suggest where?In Electrum or Electrum cash?and there is some procedure that I can follow? I am not still confident in this new technology. And if is a Multisig address?

Comment: This does not work with Electrum and Electrum Cash you need to manually create such a raw transaction. You can use all tools that can be used to create such a raw transaction in bitcoin, because you do not need to hash and sign the transaction. Such tools are for example [libbitcoin-explorer](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer) or you could create one with a library such as [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib). If it is a multisig address you need to figure out the public keys and the configuration of the multisig address.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, there are some manuals to make a raw transaction? and sorry if I ask you but this address has 3 different public address but when I imported the private key show me a different address... could you explain me why?

Comment: If this is a multisig address, you need to use bitcoin cash tools as this requires hashing and signing. This can also be done in electron cash. You just need to create a multi sig wallet in electron cash and add all cosigner private keys. You can just look at the [electrum documentation](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/multisig.html#create-a-pair-of-2-of-2-wallets). You then have to figure out the configuration. For this you can just create a 1-3, 2-3 and 3-3 multi sig address and check if there is any balance.